# Accessibility Guideline I Don't Understand

Tags: html, accessibility

I'm looking over a list of guidelines for compliance with the Americans with Disabilities Act. I don't understand this one:

> When text is not available use the title attribute

What on Earth does this mean? When would text not be "available"?

Comment: Exists a public/linkable document in which this is said?

Comment: @unor, yes, this is from a U.S. Federal Government document. Check out http://inbound.anchorstl.com/ada-compliance-and-your-website-are-you-compliant/ or just Google the rule in quotes (for an exact match).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"When text is not available" - Any time you have content meant to communicate something but don't have text explaining it. So while a graphical icon would apply (even if it has text in the image itself), so would a text input that doesn't have a label.

[W3C - Using the title attribute to identify form controls when the label element cannot be used](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H65.html)

However, an image that's not used to communicate something should not include it (the example here is a squiggle line):

[W3C - Using null alt text and no title attribute on img elements for images that AT should ignore](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H67.html)

Full Document: [W3C - Techniques for WCAG 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/Overview.html#contents)

Answer (score 2):

Well Stack Overflow has several of these. Look at the top bar to the left of your reputation. You'll see several buttons. What are these buttons, I wonder?

Thanks to the `title` attribute being appropriately set, we can find out!

[image: Example Image]

Comment: OK, so does "when text is not available" basically mean "whenever you're using a graphical icon with no textual context, e.g. a label"? If so, the guideline would (for example) mandate use of "title" for that inbox icon you show in your answer, but would not mandate "title" if the icon were labeled. What if the icon picture incorporates the word "inbox," though? I'm assuming that "title" would still be required, for screen readers and whatnot.